# A 4-bit combinatorial circuit that outputs 1 when integer greater than 7 and is odd number

Tags: logic, computer-science, combinatorics, circuit

If I segment the 4-bit input as r x y z where if the input was 8, the 4-bits would be 1 0 0 1. I know that r and z must have an AND gate but cannot figure out a way to get x y to work. I drew a truth table and found that

- 1 0 0 1
- 1 0 1 1
- 1 1 0 1
- 1 1 1 1

must all equal to 1 to satisfy the condition placed.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? Ideally, specific to coding? If this is a CS question, you could research over at https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I need to draw a combinatorial circuit @jdv

Comment: I think you should direct your research to a maths or CS Stack Exchange site then. This is not on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

x and y dont matter in this situation since every possible answer has some combination of the x and y variables. So your minimum expression for this circuit is `r AND z`

its a good exercise to see why though `r and z and ((x and y) or (x' and y) or (x and y') or (x' and y'))`. is also a valid expression for the circuit. Try to see why we can simplify this with Boolean algebra

Comment: That's not a valid expression though, 0 0 0 0 would give a 1 output because of the not x ^ not y gate.

Comment: @JJMin but its anded with r and z which are both 0